# Split rows to create new rows in Pandas Dataframe with same other row values

Tags: python, pandas, split, explode

I have a pandas dataframe in which one column of text strings contains multiple comma-separated values. I want to split each field and create a new row per entry only where the number of commas is >= 2. For example, a should become b:

```
In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
    var1     var2   var3
0  a,b,c,d     1     X1
1  a,b,c,d     1     X2
2  a,b,c,d     1     X3
3  a,b,c,d     1     
4  e,f,g       2     Y1
5  e,f,g       2     Y2
6  e,f,g       2     
7  h,i         3     Z1
In [8]: b
Out[8]: 
     var1  var2   var3
0    a,d     1     X1
1    b,d     1     X2
3    c,d     1     X3
4    e,g     2     Y1
5    f,g     2     Y2
6    h,i     3     Z1
```

Comment: i didn't understand how do you choose in a,b,c,d which of the pair will be var, it can be ab, ac, ad, bd, bc, bd, cd..

Comment: @Tomer S it has to be paired with the last element. Each of the first 1,2,3....n-1 elements have to be paired with the nth element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by splitting `var1` on the comma into lists. The integer in `var3` minus 1 can be interpreterd as the index of what item in the list in `var1` to keep:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''    var1     var2   var3
0  a,b,c,d     1     X1
1  a,b,c,d     1     X2
2  a,b,c,d     1     X3
3  a,b,c,d     1     
4  e,f,g       2     Y1
5  e,f,g       2     Y2
6  e,f,g       2     
7  h,i         3     Z1'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep = r'\s\s+', engine='python')
df['var1'] = df["var1"].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: [[i,x[-1]] for i in x[:-1]]) #split the string to list and create combinations of all items with the last item in the list
df = df[df['var3'].notnull()] # drop rows where var3 is None
df['var1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['var1'][0 if not x['var3'] else int(x['var3'][1:])-1], axis=1) #keep only the element in the list in var1 where the index is the integer in var3 minus 1
```

Output:

|  | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ['a', 'd'] | 1 | X1 |
| 1 | ['b', 'd'] | 1 | X2 |
| 2 | ['c', 'd'] | 1 | X3 |
| 4 | ['e', 'g'] | 2 | Y1 |
| 5 | ['f', 'g'] | 2 | Y2 |
| 7 | ['h', 'i'] | 3 | Z1 |

Run `df['var1'] = df['var1'].str.join(',')` to reconvert `var1` to a string.

Comment: I like the way you play with the index inside the apply, whereas I use cumcount.  I think you drop the last (extra) item by drop the null in var3 whereas I drop based on nan  (which has a danger if cells have a nan).  btw, what IDE you use ?  It generates a excel-like table.

Comment: @EBDS stackoverflow can parse markdown tables. Just copy and paste the output of `print(df.to_markdown())`. Make sure there is an empty line between the table and preceding text, otherwise SO won't parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom function:

```
def custom_split(r):
    if r['var3']:
        s = r['var1']
        i = int(r['var3'][1:])-1
        l = s.split(',')
        return l[i]+','+l[-1]

df['var1'] = df.apply(custom_split, axis=1)
df = df.dropna()
```

output:

```
  var1  var2 var3
0  a,d     1   X1
1  b,d     1   X2
2  c,d     1   X3
4  e,g     2   Y1
5  f,g     2   Y2
7  h,i     3   Z1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['cc'] = df.groupby('var1')['var1'].cumcount()
df['var1'] = df['var1'].str.split(',')
df['var1'] = df[['cc','var1']].apply(lambda x: x['var1'][x['cc']]+','+x['var1'][-1],axis=1)
df = df.dropna().drop(columns=['cc']).reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

[image]

Comment: How come all three answers got voted down ???

Comment: Must be someone with a bad mood, I gave you an upvote to make up for it

Comment: Ok.  I return you one.  ;-)